# Supremum of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $B_r$ be a ball of radius $r$ centered at $0$ and $u:B_r\times[t_1,t_2]\to(0,\infty)$ be an $L^p$ integrable function. Define the integral
$$
\sup_{t_1<t<t_2}\int_{B_r}u^p(x,t)\,dx.
$$
Then is it possible to choose $\tau\in[t_1,t_2]$ such that
$$
\int_{B_r}u^p(x,\tau)\,dx=\sup_{t_1<t<t_2}\int_{B_r}u^p(x,t)\,dx?
$$
Even for continuous function? Thanks.

Is it even possible for continuous function. I have seen such results are possible written in just one line. For example in the article: Equation (28)
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.07649.pdf

Can somebody kindly help me. Thanks.

Comment: No, certainly not. Define $u(x,t)=t$ on $(-1,1)\times (0,1).$

Comment: I hae edited the question, $\tau\in[t_1,t_2]$.

Comment: But $u$ is not defined there.

Comment: Suppose defined. I have edited. Thanks.

Comment: Is $B_r$ closed? And do your new hypotheses correspond to those in the paper?

Comment: Yes. Also u can take $B_r$ to be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $B_r$ is closed, then $B_r\times [t_1,t_2]$ is compact. So if $u: B_r\times [t_1,t_2]\to (0,\infty)$ is continuous, then $u$ is uniformly continuous there. Hence $u^p$ is uniformly continuous there. It follows that the function

$$t\to \int_{B_r} u^p(x,t)\,dx$$

is continuous on $[t_1,t_2].$ Hence it acheives a maximum at some $c\in [t_1,t_2].$ This gives the desired result for continuous $u.$

If $u$ is not continuous, there should be easy counterexamples.